# TCP Packet Sending Error

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, webcam, packet

I'm making a webcam app that sends and receives small images. I have made it be able to send and receive, I tested on 127.0.0.1 and it worked fine, but now I'm using my own external IP address and it seems to send one image, receive one, then mess up, I get some sort of massive integer value in the image size, a minus value which leads it to crash, I think maybe the receive and send are running on their own, and are going out of sync somehow. I put a 1000ms delay before sending out each image and it was slow but working, as soon as I take the delay out, it messes up.

Here is the code :

```
    // This sends.
    private void NewFrameReceived(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap img = (Bitmap)e.Frame.Clone();

        byte[] imgBytes = EncodeToJpeg(img, 25).ToArray();
        if (_tcpOut.Connected)
        {
            NetworkStream ns = _tcpOut.GetStream();
            if (ns.CanWrite)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                ns.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(imgBytes.Length), 0, 4);
                ns.Write(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    // This receives.
    private void listeningThread_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // start listening for connections
        _tcpIn = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 54321);
        _tcpIn.Start();

        TcpClient _inClient = _tcpIn.AcceptTcpClient();
        while (true)
        {
            NetworkStream ns = _inClient.GetStream();
            if (ns.CanRead && ns.DataAvailable)
            {
                Byte[] imgSizeBytes = new Byte[4];
                ns.Read(imgSizeBytes, 0, 4);
                int imgSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(imgSizeBytes, 0);

                Byte[] imgBytes = new Byte[imgSize];  <-- ERROR, GET CRAZY LARGE VALUE
                ns.Read(imgBytes, 0, imgSize);

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgBytes);
                Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);

                picVideo.Image = img;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the exception you're getting?

Comment: Hi, sometimes I get "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow." and sometimes memory overflow. (also error line was the line below -- corrected)

Comment: There are too many variables and unknowns to be able to answer your question properly. As a first step I'd suggest checking how many bytes are actually being received from your first transmission and prove that it matches what is being sent. Depending on how big your image is you could be hitting some fragmentation of the data transmitted.

Comment: The simple way to implement Keith's suggestion is to enforce your already in place packet framing (by making sure you are actually receiving the amount of data sent by the server) and then using an *eyecatcher* of sorts (some known value that identifies the beginning of a frame). It would also help to have a way for the applications to tell each other in case they get out of sync so they can force a retransmission.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what we use tags for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Read` doesn't necessarily read as many bytes as you ask for, just as many happen to be currently available -- you should actually check the return value to see how many it read. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) might help give you a better understanding.

You should add logic to keep reading until all of the image bytes have been read. A pseudo-code example:

```
total_bytes_read = 0;
while (total_bytes_read != total_bytes_needed)
{
    bytes_left_to_read = total_bytes_needed - total_bytes_read;
    total_bytes_read += read(buffer, total_bytes_read, bytes_left_to_read);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to rethink things a little bit.....   the data could arrive in different packets.   Your read function will only read what is available.   This will lead your system to get out of synch.

I'd build a little protocol for images so I can always tell where the start and end of images are in my data stream.

you don't HAVE to do that, but it makes life easier,  you could do it purely by a simple state machine that knows how far through receiving an image it has got.  But any non compliance in sending the image ( 1 extra byte in the stream for example) could send the thing out of synch forever.

Comment: Hi many thanks for your valuable suggestion. But if I add some sort of "marker" bytes, and they come in the middle of a block of say 1024 bytes how would I know that the old image ended and a new one has started? Would I have to go through each byte of the received 1024 byte block and check for the special end flag? And which classes are best suited for join and search operations on byte array data?

Comment: One solution often used is to use escape-sequences to remove the start/end control characters from the block data.  Another way is to prefix the block with a header that contains the block length, so allowing the rx to determine when it has received a whole block and to start looking for another header.  The header should have sufficient data and redundancy to allow a header to be sanity-checked, (eg. always starts with [SOH], contains the data length and CRC in fixed-length ASCII-numeric form).  You may need a byte-by-bye state-machine at the rx. to check the header.